# Browser not rendering PDF correctly in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, view, dompdf

[image: On my localhost][image: on my server]

Localhost is fine but when uploaded to server not working

## My Code

```
public function printSalesRecord()
{

    $setPaperSize = 'A4';
    $pdf = App::make('dompdf');


    $pdf = PDF::loadView('salesrecord/PrintSalesRecord')->setPaper($setPaperSize)->setOrientation('portraite');

    return $pdf->stream();

}
```

## This is what i get on my browser

%PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 8 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Creator (DOMPDF) /CreationDate (D:20161122092040+00'00') /ModDate (D:20161122092040+00'00') >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 73 >> stream x��2�300P@&�ҹ�B�M���-L�L�,BR����B��5JR�K�Drr�f�B���k��� endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj xref 0 9 0000000000 65535 f 0000000009 00000 n 0000000074 00000 n 0000000120 00000 n 0000000274 00000 n 0000000303 00000 n 0000000417 00000 n 0000000480 00000 n 0000000624 00000 n trailer << /Size 9 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R >> startxref 733 %%EOF

Comment: It's very difficult to say that if you ask like that on Stackoverflow. Can you specific more ?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, add this at the end of the script or function:

```
exit();
```

Comment: Working as charm in symfony controller. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please double check for **vendor:publish**

It's look like your pdf may contain utf-8 character.

**Tip: UTF-8 support**

You need to add this in your template file if you want to have support for UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Another possibility;

Can you change font directory from **/BaseFont/dompdf/lib/fonts/Times-Roman** to **/BaseFont/Times-Roman**?

Comment: after added to this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> in template. Same Problem

Comment: I just only have this code nothing much on template

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

test test ccc

Comment: I want you to show in your question for your blade file <head> tag

Answer (score 0):

Try adding response header to your Laravel code

```
Response::header('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
```

Or just add `.pdf` extension to your route .

Or use `download()` function instead of `stream()`

Answer (score -1):

Main Reason That Some Fonts cause this error , make sure to set this font , it will work properly :)

```
 <style>
            * {
                font-family: DejaVu Sans;
            }
    </style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add support for UTF-8 in the file you are loading. Here is a sample code that worked for me

```
    $checkedProducts = $request->input('products');

    $pdf = App::make( 'dompdf.wrapper' );
    $html ='<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"</head><body>
                <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                             <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>';
                                    for($i = 0; $i<count($checkedProducts); $i++){
                                        $products = DB::table('products')->where('id', $checkedProducts[$i] )->value('name');
                                        $html.= '<tr><td>'. $products .'</td></tr>';
                                    }

                                $html.= '</tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html> ';
    $pdf->loadHTML($html);
    return $pdf->download( 'quote.pdf' );  
}
```

I had loaded the PDF file without the html tags and got the same problem as yours. I added them and also added the meta tag with UTF-8 support and worked fine.

Comment: This is not an optimal solution, view specific data should not be inside a controller method. You should improve your answer with e.g. loadview('blade template', data).